# Finite algebraic set are discrete

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

In "Commutative Algebra with a view towrd Algebraic Geometry", page 38, Eisenbud says that every finite algebraic set has the discrete topology. How to prove that? I see that this is the case of algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}^1$.

Comment: As a first step, you might like to show that every point is closed.

Comment: It may not be obvious at first, but [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1141439/200415) (and its answers) are essentially answering your question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found thanks to Zhen Lin: the points are closed because $A=(a_i)_i$ is $Z(X_i-a_i)_i$ and because the set is finit then it is discret.