# In a finitely generated $k$-algebra, the nilradical is $0$ iff the Jacobson radical is $0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I was solving an exercise in Vakil's notes *Foundations of Algebraic Geometry* 3.6.K, and eventually proved the following statement:

> Let $\mathscr{A}$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra, where $k$ is any field. Then $\mathscr{N}(\mathscr{A}) = 0\iff \mathscr{R}(\mathscr{A}) = 0$. (All $k$-algebras are commutative here.)

Here is my proof for the hard direction:

> Let $0\ne f\in \mathscr{A}$, then $D(f) = \{P \in Spec \mathscr{A}: f\not\in P\}\ne \varnothing$ since $\mathscr{N}(\mathscr{A})= 0$. By Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, if $\mathscr{A}$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, any non-empty basic open set $D(f)$ contains a closed point $M$. We conclude that $f\not\in M$.

Does this look correct? Can someone please point to me where this is covered in Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra*? And is this statement equivalent to Nullstellensatz?

Comment: Take a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_ring , then check that a finite dimensional algebra over a field is a Jacobson ring. It wouldn't hurt proving the result or understanding the proof.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This statement is much easier than the Nullstellensatz, and admits a straightforward direct proof.

The key point is that a finite dim'l algebra over $k$ is a domain iff it is a field.

This shows that in a finite dim'l algebra over a field, an ideal is prime iff it is maximal.

This in turn shows that for finite dim'l algebras over a field, the nilradical and Jacobson radical coincide.

The Nullstellensatz is much deeper: it involves showing that a finite type algebra over $k$ that is a field is in fact finite dim'l over $k$.  In your setting of finite dim'l algs. over a field, finite dimensionality is automatic; you don't need to apply the Nullstellensatz to get it.

Added: This answered an earlier version of the question, which had a typo.  See the comments for a discussion and clarification in light of the revised question.

Comment: Very nice. I didn't notice that it was finitely generated as a *vector space*. This is easier, although I think there is still something to prove, as you say.

Comment: Ops! I really meant finitely generated every time I typed finite dim. Sorry about this huge typo.

Comment: @mez: Okay, then yes, this is a reformulation of the Nullstellensatz; the link to wikipedia on Jacobson rings given above should spell this out, and your argument is also a standard way of thinking about it. (There are many statements here, such as the Nullstellensatz, the equality of nilrad and Jacobson rad, the existence of closed points on non-empty varieties, etc., which are closely related and all more-or-less imply each other --- so which one you take as a starting point and which ones you regard as consequences depends a bit on your view-point and the precise chain of argument adopted.)

Answer (score 2):

With the correction I think the proof is right, if a little slim on details. If it's just for your own use then I think it's great!

In Eisenbud look at the discussion of Jacobson rings in Section 4.5. If you want another presentation of the material there, there is a lot of overlap with [this note](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~emerton/pdffiles/jacobson.pdf) of Emerton's.

Comment: $\mathscr{N}$ denotes the nilradical, $\mathscr{R}$ denotes the Jacobson radical. I am assuming only $\mathscr{N}(\mathscr{A}) = 0$, that tells me that $D(f)\ne \varnothing$.

Comment: @mez: If you look at your second highlighted paragraph, you write $\mathscr N (\mathscr A) \neq 0,$ when you mean $ =0$.